# Parameter in commands SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, parameters

This is the syntax for parameterised SQL in MySQL - the parameter is `?`.

```
SELECT *
FROM tb_accounts 
WHERE  id= ? AND password= ?
```

What is the correct syntax for parameterised queries in SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @id int = 123,@password varchar(100) = 'MyPass1!'

SELECT * 
FROM tb_accounts 
WHERE id = @id AND password = @password
```

---

[DECLARE @local_variable (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188927.aspx)

(check the **Examples** section)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use dynamic SQL query like this for selecting data by passing parameter dynamically.

```
sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM tb_accounts WHERE id = @id AND password = @password',N'@id int,@password varchar(100)',@id=123,@password='MyPassword'
```